# Why the abaqus job name is not updating in my abaqus python script?

Tags: python, abaqus

I am doing the simulation for different combinations of material properties (i, j, m) iteratively.
So I am trying to create the job names Job1, Job2, Job3,......till the end of the loop.
But my current code creates the job name as Job1 and again and again as Job1.
Because of that, the files are overwritten.[Problem Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe67H.png)

```
for i in arange(1, 3, 1):
    for j in arange(0.35, 0.36, 0.02):
        for m in arange(1.67e-08, 1.68e-08, 2e-10):
            # k - i 100 - , l - j 100, n - m 1e8
            i_ = int()
            j_ = (i_+1)
            # Create job name based on loop values
            job_name = 'Job%d' % (j_)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python [uses names](https://david.goodger.org/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names), so you don't need to declare types like this

Just drop naming `_i = int()` (which becomes `0`) and use `i` directly

```py
>>> a = int()
>>> a
0
```

```py
for i in arange(1, 3, 1):
    for j in arange(0.35, 0.36, 0.02):
        for m in arange(1.67e-08, 1.68e-08, 2e-10):
            # k - i 100 - , l - j 100, n - m 1e8
            # Create job name based on loop values
            job_name  = "Job{}".format(i+1)
```

Comment: `f` strings are not available in Abaqus as it still uses Python 2. So please use `%d`: `job_name = 'Job_%d' % (i+1)`.

Comment: @SatishThorat interesting/edited (I'd suggest `.format()`, but I don't have a way to test it)! you can always suggest an [edit] to gain some reputation too!